# What's the symbolism of the flowers in The Winter's Tale?

Tags: symbolism, william-shakespeare, the-winters-tale

In Act IV, Scene IV of *The Winter's Tale*, Perdita is "mistress o' the feast", playing hostess at the sheep-shearing feast, when King Polixenes and Camillo arrive in disguise. Perdita gives them both flowers, accompanied by the following short speech:

> Give me those flowers there, Dorcas. Reverend sirs,
>   For you there's rosemary and rue; these keep
>   Seeming and savour all the winter long:
>   Grace and remembrance be to you both,
>   And welcome to our shearing!

But it doesn't end there. She and Polixenes, along with Florizel and Camillo, talk at *length* about flowers for the next 60-odd lines. (I won't quote all those lines here, since the full text of the play is freely available and easy to find online, for example [here](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/winters_tale/full.html).)

When I saw *The Winter's Tale* performed in the theatre, this conversation was actually cut out, as were some later sections of the sheep-shearing feast in this very long scene. But I remember hearing that the conversation about flowers had some special significance and symbolism relating to the plot.

**Is there more to this conversation than just idle chat about flowers?** If so, what is the hidden meaning and/or symbolism?

Comment: I haven't read or seen the play, but does there need to be symbolism?

Comment: @Shokhet It's pretty reasonable to presume that adding 60 lines about flowers has some meaning.

Comment: There was an Elizabethan "language" to flowers in which various species were assigned specific meanings, e.g. rosemary = remembrance.  There are many "cribs" to the _other_ big flower scene in Shakespeare (Hamlet IV, ii) on the internets, such as this one:  https://hamletdramaturgy.wordpress.com/2013/02/20/ophelias-flowers/  I'm sure a JSTOR search would turn up a journal article or two on the Winter's Tale scene....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two strands of allusions or associations in the long exchange about flowers: one about nature versus "art" and another about the associations of specific flowers.

### Nature versus "Art"

The **debate of nature versus "art"** ("art" had a broader meaning and here also includes the craft of gardening)
is illustrated in the following exchange between Perdita and Polixenes (emphasis added):

> **Perdita**: (..) our carnations and streak'd gillyvors,
> Which some call **nature's bastards**: of that kind
> Our rustic garden's barren; and I care not
> To get slips of them.
> **Polixenes**: Wherefore, gentle maiden,
> Do you neglect them?
> **Perdita**: For I have heard it said
> There is an **art** which in their piedness shares
> With great creating **nature**.
> **Polixenes**: Say there be;
> Yet **nature is made better by no mean
>
> But nature makes that mean**: so, over that art
> Which you say adds to nature, is **an art
>
> That nature makes**. You see, sweet maid, we marry
> A gentler scion to the wildest stock,
> And make conceive a bark of baser kind
> By bud of nobler race: this is an art
> Which does mend nature, change it rather, but
> **The art itself is nature**.
> **Perdita**: So it is.
> **Polixenes**: Then make your garden rich in gillyvors,
> And do not call them bastards.

Perdita does not wish to give Polixenes and Camillo any carnations or gillyflowers
because there are hybrids ("bastards") developed by gardeners,
as opposed to flowers that nature produced.
Polixenes does not simply respond that "art" is the equal of or even superior to nature;
his stance is more subtle, since he claims that even the gardener's craft
is a product of nature ("an art / That nature makes").

Perdita's position reflects that of [Montaigne's essay "Of cannibals"](https://archive.org/details/essayestranslate02montuoft/page/54/mode/2up),
in which the French thinker said (in John Florio's 1603 translation; emphasis added),

> They are even savage, as we call those fruits wilde which **nature of her selfe**
> and of her ordinarie progresse hath produced : whereas indeed, they are those
> which our selves have **altered by our artificiall devicesand diverted from their
> common order, we should rather terme savage. In those are the true and most
> profitable vertues, and naturall properties most lively and vigorous, which in these
> we have **bastardized**, applying them to the pleasure of our corrupted taste.

A contemporary formulation of Polixenes's position can be found in
George Puttenham's *The Art of English Poesie* (1589):

> In ſome cafes we ſay **arte is an ayde and coadiutor to nature**, and a furtherer of her actions to good effect,
> or peraduenture **a meane to ſupply her wants**, by renforcing the cauſes wherein ſhee is impotent and defecting.
> as doth the arte of phiſicke, by helping the naturall concoction, retention, diſtribution, expulſion, and other
> vertues, in a weake and vnhealthie bodie. Or as the good gardiner ſeaſons his ſoyle by ſundrie ſorts of compoſt
> (...)
> In another reſpect arte is not only an aide and coadiutor to nature in all heraclions, but an alterer of them,
> and in ſome ſort **a ſurmounter of her skill**, ſo as by meanes of it her owne effects ſhall appeare more
> beautifull or ſtraunge and miraculous, as in both caſes before remembred.

(Note that the theme of art as *imitation* of nature is mentioned in Act V, scene 2, in the discussion of the statue of Hermione.)

It perfectly fits Perdita's character to defend unadulterated nature, since she grew up in an uncomplicated rural environment.
Her words reinforce her portrayal as an ideal pastoral character.

Contrary to [Joshua Engel's claim](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/1700/2191), the above passage from the play
is not about the engagement between Perdita and Florizel, at least not from Polixenes's point of view.
There is no evidence that the king is not serious here or later in the scene,
when he disowns Florizel for wanting to marry Perdita.
However, the exchange on grafting and creating hybrids creates dramatic irony due to its contrast with Polixenes's reaction later in the scene.
(Note that theatregoers in Shakespeare's time would not have been surprised about the king's reaction to the engagement between Florizel and Perdita.)

There is also dramatic irony in the sense that Perdita is of noble birth but certain circumstances have "grafted" her onto a pastoral environment.
Shakespeare here reuses the theme of a noble birth that still shines through in a completely different environment,
which he had also used in *Cymbeline*, in which the kidnapped princes Guiderius and Arviragus grew up in a cave.

### Associations of flowers

The exchange about nature versus art interrupts the flower giving by Perdita.
The flowers in this scene have different associations or meanings.

- **rosemary**: remembrance, as explicitly mentioned by Perdita,
  and by Ophelia in [*Hamlet*, Act IV, scene 5](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/hamlet/hamlet.4.5.html).
- **rue**: Ophelia says of this plant (*Hamlet*, Act IV, scene 5): "we may call it / herb-grace o' Sundays".
  Perdita wishes Polixenes and Camillo to be remembered after their deaths and to achieve divine grace.
- **carnations** and **gilly-flowers** (or clove-scented pinks): it is not clear whether these have any "symoblic" meaning;
  they lead into the debate about nature versus art discussed above. In addition, the first flowers Perdita had given are "flowers of winter",
  whereas now she gives them flowers of (mid)summer, wich, in Perdita's words, are appropriate for "men of middle age".
- **hot lavender**: herbs were classified as "hot" or "cold" in a way similar to the classification of temperaments according to the
  [theory of humours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_temperaments).
- **mint**: (no specific associations).
- **savoury**: (no specific associations).
- **marjoram**: (no specific associations, but the herb was popular in soups and other dishes and was also used as a "strewing herb" on floors; see Jessica Kerr: *Shakespeare's Flowers*. Kestrel Books, 1969, page 61).
- **marigold**: This flower closes its petals at sundown and opens them again at sunrise, presumably "weeping" because wet with dew. It was also referred to as "Sponsus solis", the spouse of the sun.
- **daffodils**: Jessica Kerr (page 75) mentions "the belief, found in early plant lore, that those spring flowers that hang their heads, such as daffodils, violets, and snow-drops, symbolize grief and tears."
- **violets**: See above. In addition, Kerr (page 46) also points out that the violet was sometimes pitied by poets for the shortness of its life; "For this reason it is often associated with death, like the primrose."
- **primroses**: "[T]he primrose is pictured as dying unmarried, in early spring, before the bridegroom, Phoebus (the sun), has reached manhood." (*The Winter's Tale*, edited by Ernest Schanzer. Penguin, 1969)
- **oxlips**: These are also mentioned in [*A Midsummer Night's Dream*, Act II, scene 1](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/midsummer/midsummer.2.1.html).
  They are "natural hybrids between the cowslip (...) and the primrose" (*A Midsummer Night's Dream*, edited by R. A. Foakes. Cambridge University Press, 1984).
- **crown imperial**: According to Ernest Schanzer, this is "the tall, yellow fritillary (which had been introduced to England from Constantinople in the 1590s)".
- **lilies, flower-de-luce**: According to Ernest Schanzer, "flower-de-luce" is "probably the iris, which was not uncommonly classed among the lilies".
  The flower-de-luce is also mentioned in other plays, e.g. [*Henry V*, Act V, scene 2](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/henryv/henryv.5.2.html)
  and [*Henry VI, Part I, Act I, scene 1](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/1henryvi/1henryvi.1.1.html).

I have avoided the term "symbolism" because Perdita, like Ophelia in *Hamlet*, finds it necessary to explicitly add what some of these flowers stand for.
Some flowers don't seem to have any specific "meaning" or none that seems directly relevant.
However, several of the spring flowers that Perdita gives to Florizel are associated with grief, a short life or death.

### Perdita and Proserpina

The flower catalogue also links Perdita with the Roman goddess [Proserpina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proserpina). In Book V of [Arthur Golding's translation of Ovid's *Metamorphoses*](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Metamorphoses_(tr._Golding)/Book_5), a translation that Shakespeare knew, we find the following passage about Proserpina:

> While in this garden Proserpine was taking hir pastime,
> In gathering eyther Violets blew, or Lillies white as Lime,
> And while of Maidenly desire she fillde hir Maund and Lap,
> Endevoring to outgather hir companions there, by hap
> Dis spide hir: lovde hir: caught hir up: (...)

(Ovid uses the names [Dis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C4%ABs_Pater) and [Pluto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluto_(mythology)) interchangeably.)

In his introduction to the Oxford Shakespeare edition of *The Winter's Tale* (page 43), Stephen Orgel writes (my emphasis):

> The classic model for the destructive intrusion of royalty into pastoral is invoked by Perdita herself: the appearance of Dis, King of the Underworld, to carry Proserpina off from the Sicilian field of Enna **as she gathers the flowers Perdita catalogues**.

(It is worth pointing out that in Shakespeare's source, Robert Greene's "novel" *Pandosto*, the corresponding scene is set in Sicily instead of Bohemia. In switching Bohemia and Sicily while adapting his source material into a play, Shakespeare appears to have weakened the parallel between Perdita and Proserpina.)

Answer (score 4):

The most important element is to introduce Polixines' thoughts on, uh, selective breeding:

> You see, sweet maid, we marry
>   A gentler scion to the wildest stock,
>   And make conceive a bark of baser kind
>   By bud of nobler race:

This is a not-so-subtle commentary on the engagement of Perdita and Florizel: she is the wilder stock, though he can also see her latent nobility. She refuses that kind of breeding, through the metaphor of the gillyvor (carnation).

The rest is a commentary on age and time, "a sad tale best fit for winter". It starts with rosemary and rue, both familiar from Ophelia's own flower speech: rosemary for remembrance, and rue as a homonym for regret. This is a moment where the last kings are passing into age, while Perdita and Florizel are the bloom of youth. Seasonal tropes recur throughout the play, a meditation on the the cycle of growing up, having children, and growing old.

Comment: I've decided to downvote this answer. You do point out an important element of the Scene IV (Shakespeare's ideas about race, gender, and sexuality). But that is all this answer does; it doesn't tie this passage into the broader themes of the play, or go into depth about any of the other elements of the scene. In sum, this answer doesn't show a lot of effort.

Comment: I felt that was the goal of the entire last paragraph.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your last paragraph isn't detailed enough to accomplish that.

Comment: OK. I hope somebody comes along and writes a more detailed answer. I have not directed this play; I only played a minor role. So my answers about it will be less detailed than ones about plays I directed or was otherwise intimately involved in. But I think it's helpful enough for me to leave it up, so I won't delete it.

Comment: I've upvoted this because it's a decent answer, but it's possible to do *much* better. It's quite short currently, and could stand to have a lot more detail, supported with more extensive quotes, about both the breeding thing (and its symbolism and irony within the play as a whole) and the age thing. The last sentence in particular could be expanded on, as it's something I don't recall noticing when studying that play. I'd like to encourage you to put more time into this one - it could be the seeds of a really excellent answer.

Comment: Upvoted; and I disagree that it's the answerer's job to "do much better". The question asked about the symbolism of the flowers. The answer provided an immediate context (breeding); a tie-in to larger themes of the play (aging, seasons); a link to another play by Shakespeare (Hamlet); and through that link, the wider context of the Elizabethan language of flowers. That is huge. IMO it's up to the asker to follow up on those pointers if the asker wants to know more. The answer is complete as it stands.

Comment: @verbose to clarify my downvote. It's not because the answer doesn't cover every detail and every possible interpretation of the scene. It's because the answer's analysis of the theme of "breeding" isn't very thorough or well thought out. This is evidenced by the fact that the answer uses the word "breeding" in the first place (that's just not a good word to use in this context), by the fact that the answer is only supported by one quote, by the fact that the answer doesn't really do a good job of explaining how "breeding" ties in with the larger themes of the play, etc. etc.

Comment: I believe breeding is precisely the word to use there. That's the subject that Polixines is discussing, using the word "stock". It's the awkwardness of the concept, exemplified by the awkwardness of "breeding", that Perdita is rejecting. I signaled that with the word "um", to introduce to the reader that this was an uncomfortable topic.

I certainly could have worked it out in more detail, but the word choice was deliberate and I stand by it.

Comment: @JoshuaEngel the language is only a small part of the problems with this answer, so I don't want to quibble about it too much, but phrases like "social reproduction" or "misgenation" might have been more accurate ways to describe what's going on in this scene.